# Calculating an integral using Dominant convergence theorem

Tags: lebesgue-integral

**Let $f \in L^1(0,\infty)$ be non-negative. Calculate     $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^n xf(x)dx$.**

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^n xf(x)dx$ = $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{n}xf(x)\chi_{[0,n]} dx$.
If we define $g_{n}(x)$:= $\frac{1}{n}xf(x)\chi_{[0,n]}$, then obviously $g_{n}$ $\to$ $0$.
How can we find a dominant function for $\frac{1}{n}xf(x)\chi_{[0,n]}$?
I though about change of variable by defining $y:=\frac{x}{n}$, but still I couldn't find a dominant function.

Comment: This question is still listed as an unanswered question. There is a simple valid answer below  and you should consider approving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that, since
$$
0\leq  \frac{x}{n}\chi_{[0,n]}(x) \leq 1,
\qquad \forall x\geq 0,
$$
one has, for every $n\geq 1$,
$$
|g_n(x)| \leq |f(x)|, \qquad \forall x\geq 0.
$$